# How get button Text from MyControl(Button)?

Tags: c#, get, controls, set

I have a problem.

**UserControl**

```
Button : UserControl
...
public string naz
{ get { return this.button1.Text; } }
...
```

On my form I can do this

```
if(button0.naz == "1"){ MessageBox.Show("My Text"); }
if(button1.naz == "1"){ MessageBox.Show("My Text"); }
if(button2.naz == "1"){ MessageBox.Show("My Text"); }
```

But when I try the following `.naz` is not recognized.

```
for(int i=0;i<=60;i++)
{
    if(this.Controls["button" + i.ToString()).naz == "1")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("My Text"); 
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the control to the type of your user control. If your class is really called `Button` then something like this

```
var myButton = this.Controls["button" + i] as Button;
if(myButton != null && myButton.naz == "1")
...
```